# SlidesJS - Have multiple "product" example sliders on 1 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the SlidesJS product example found here http://slidesjs.com/examples/product/

I want to have more than 1 of these units on the page, but when just copying the markup for it and pasting below doesn't work right. The first one will show up fine, but the second one only shows the 2 pagination elements and are unclickable. My main question is why would my approach of just copying the slider again not work, and is my general approach totally wrong? Is there some quirk with SlidesJS or Jquery in general that requires me to create separate css divs or something like that?

HTML:

```
<div id="containerSlides">
      <div id="products_example">
        <div id="products">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/lamp1.png" width="360" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a>
                <a href="#" ><img src="img/lamp2.png" width="360" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a>

            </div>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lamp1.png" width="55" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lamp2.png" width="55" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="containerSlides">
      <div id="products_example">
        <div id="products">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/lamp3.png" width="360" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a>
                <a href="#" ><img src="img/lamp4.png" width="360" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a>

            </div>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lamp3.png" width="55" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lamp4.png" width="55" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#containerSlides {
    width:580px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    float:left;
}

#products_example {
    width:600px;
    height:282px;
    position:relative;
}

/*
    Slideshow
*/

#products {
    margin-left:26px;
}

/*
    Slides container
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides container
    Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/

#products .slides_container {
    width:360px;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    display:none;
}

/*
    Each slide
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides
    If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
    Set to display block
*/

.slides_container a {
    width:360px;
    height:268px;
    display:block;
}

/*
    Next/prev buttons
*/

#products .next,#products .prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:127px;
    left:0;
    width:21px;
    height:0;
    padding-top:21px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    z-index:101;
}

#products .prev {
    background:url(../img/arrow-prev.png);
}

#products .next {
    left:398px;
    background:url(../img/arrow-next.png);
}

/*
    Pagination
*/

#products .pagination {

    width:55px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
}

#products .pagination li {
    float:left;
    margin:2px 4px;
    list-style:none;
}

#products .pagination li a {
    display:block;
    width:55px;
    height:41px;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
    background:#f9f9f9;
}

#products .pagination li.current a {
    border:1px solid #7f7f7f;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the javascript its impossible to say exactly where the issue is, however there are some immediate issues with the markup.

You have multiple elements on the page with the same id's (containerSlides, products_example, products).

Giving the second container unique id's will help solve the problem. You will then probably (again, cant say for sure without seeing the javascript) need to add another 'initialization' call to set up slidesjs on the second container as well as adding the id to your css so that the second container gets the same styling.

Ex:

Markup

```
<code>
<div id="secondContainerSlides">
    …
</div>
</code>
```

Css

```
<code>
#containerSlides,
#secondContainerSlides{
    …
}
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was overlooking. For some reason I was looking at the ids like they were just a general tag, not a unique identifier.